# Difference between $H_0^2$ and $H^2 \cap H_0^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

What's the difference between Hilbert space $H_0^2$ and $H_0^1 \cap H^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, functions in $H_0^2$ have also derivatives which vanish on the boundary.

To be precise, the function
$$f(x) = 1-x^2$$
belongs to $H_0^1(-1,1) \cup H^2(-1,1)$ but not to $H_0^2(0,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I typed the false question, and I edit the question which I want to ask.